# Pagination api for huge number of records

Tags: api-design

I have an api which returns records given some constraint. Let's say 50000 records meet the constraint. Because we can not return all the records at once, so I have to implement pagination. I am also showing that there are more pages of records. To solve this  i am Counting the total number of record that match the constraint.

The problem is that **counting number of records takes a lot of time**. Are there optimisation to count number of records? Or are there more efficient ways to deal with this? For example just check if there are pending records rather than getting count of records all the time.

our count query requires 3 table joins. when it is trying to fetch count ~15000, it is taking around 1 second. But our application latencies are much stricter than this.

Comment: Please clarify the scenario - why and when do you need to count the records?

Comment: i have updated the question to be more precise. I need either number of pages or number or records so that i can show that there are more records.

Comment: if you "need the count" but also "can't do the count" how can anyone answer that? what database are you using, what cols do you have, whats an example query, why is it slow? etc etc

Comment: fair question, i was thinking of innovative strategies like rather than counting all rows, if i could see there is a next element to my current range.

Comment: Joining on three tables should be easy for a relational database to handle. Without more information about the database, tables, and what optimizations you've already done, I don't see how we can answer your question. My intuition says you should fine tune indexes in your database. It's a common misconception that joins are slow.

Comment: I am not saying joins are slow, but just count(star) in the case of lots of records is coming out to be slow.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't efficiently count them, estimate using whatever precise or crude method may be applicable.

- One simple (most crude) way would be to return a "more to come" flag if you're not at the end of the query yet.
- A better way would be to use the database `count(*)` operation when the constraints can be exactly or approximately expressed in (simple) SQL logic.
- If the records are chronologically ordered (and you can expect no modifications in past records) and your users specify only a limited set of constraint options, you may cache the daily counts for each option.

Unless your users really need to know how many records there are to come (and I would not care at all whether the number is 50000 or 500 or 5 million) the first option might be actually good enough. If you want to offer real luxury (and have the development time to do so) you might add a button "count exact number" to the UI which would perform the time consuming calculation.

Comment: I have posted a more elaborate answer taking inspiration from your insightful answer. Initially i thought of writing comment but then the content was little more than what i expected. Hope you don't mind. Thanks

Comment: I don't mind at all, getting at a good solution is often an iterative process where you build on intermediate insights and results.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be broken down into 2 parts and multiple subparts

1. Returning records based on query and pagination context

   a. Is the results stable? How does new entries in the db change the results?

   b. How much computation is needed to calculate the results. For example doing a sort by and selecting 50000th record may be computationally expensive, but finding record given a particular day may not be.
2. showing total no of page/record or showing whether there is a next page

Both the problems are interesting in their own space.

1st(a) and 1st(b) problem depends on business construct. Whether records are inserted in between or in the end always. What control we have wrt paginated query being made. How computationally expensive it is to compute the paginated response. If it is very computationally expensive or stability of query result is important but can not be guaranteed based on data model, when ever query comes first time, compute the results without pagination and insert the records in some temporary store with some ttl. And keep on serving paginated results for same query from temporary store.

2nd problem depends on number of records matching the query as mentioned in the question. Computing count in all the requests may be unnecessary. there are various ways it can be solved

**Solution 1**: Whenever first request comes compute the total count and in subsequent paginated queries don't return total page/result count. Putting the onus on the clients to manage the total pages.

**Solution 2**: Don't return total pages count at all but only a flag telling there are more records avaialble. If the request comes for 10 records, query for 11 records from the data store, if 11 records are returned then return a flag to client indicating there are more results along with 10 records.

**Solution 3**:  Approximate the number of results. Some datastores support [TABLESAMPLE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-sampling), where instead of running query on complete dataset, we execute it only on a part of the data set. In case you DB does not support this (mysql does not btw) some sort of sampling scheme can be devised. For example if day is a column in your DB and is already indexed, we could approximate count() of query by 3X(count() of query and day < 10). Choosing the appropriate approximation function depends on your usecase. Now approximations are problematic in case the results are less as inconsistencies can be easily noticed. In case approximate results are very less we can do full query without approximation and its should not take too much time since the number of records it has to count are anyways small.

Answer (score 0):

Normally getting a row count from a database, even with a filter isn't a problem, so it's unclear what the cause of your problem might be.

Having said that, if you cant get a row count and just want to say "more rows available" the answer is simple. Just get back slightly more rows than are in the page. That way if the returned rows equal the page size you know it's the last page.

Update : Given that you can get the count its just slower than the page load requirement, you could do it asynchronously, load the first page, and update the page count in the background.

Comment: to put things in perspective our count query requires 3 table joins. when it is trying to fetch count ~15000, it is taking around 1 second. But our application latencies are much stricter than this.

Comment: that the kind of detail you could have put in the question. also include the tables, indexes, execution plans etc and send the the database stack exchange